# Is it good idea to pass uninitialized variable to srand?

Tags: c++, c, srand

Is it good idea to pass uninitialized variable to `srand` instead of result of `time(NULL)`?
It is one `#include` and one function call less.

Example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    {
        usigned seed; //uninitialized
        srand(seed);
    }
    //other code
    return 0;
}
```

instead of

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    //other code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you think that *any* use of an uninitialized variable is a good idea?

Comment: Initialised doesn't mean random.  Just use time(NULL).

Comment: Unless you want to generate the same series of random numbers every time you run your program, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Uninitialized means the value in the variable is what ever was lying around in memory by the previous process or thread or stack.  Chances are it is more likely to be 0, a small number, or a pointer to some other part of memory.

Comment: no, it is not a good idea

Comment: Undefined Behavior means *anything at all could happen*.  The program might crash.  It might appear to work correctly.  It might silently corrupt memory depending on the phase of the moon.  It might erase your hard drive.  It might send your mother a nasty email.  It might make demons fly out of your nose.  There are all permitted behaviors as far as the C language is concerned.

Comment: See also [Is uninitialized local variable the fastest random number generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31739792/1708801)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it isn't.

Reading an uninitialized value results in undefined behavior. It can be zero, it can be semi-random — but as such, it can repeatedly be the same value. It may also cause compilation or runtime errors, or do any other completely unpredictable thing.

Then, someone else compiling your program will notice the compiler warning about uninitialized value and try to fix it. He may fix it correctly, or given complex enough program he may just initialize it to zero. That's how ['small' bugs turn into huge bugs](https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571).

---

Just try your snippet with `srand()` replaced by `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    {
        unsigned seed;
        printf("%u\n", seed);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On my system it repeatedly gives `0`. This means that there's at least one system where your code is broken :).

Comment: You continue on from undefined behaviour with... "It can be zero, it can be semi-random...", but that's distracting attention from the main point - it can crash or corrupt the program behaviour - all bets are off, and not just about the initial value of `seed`.

Comment: Or [it could completely optimized away the code segment etc...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/1708801)

Answer (score 8):

No, accessing uninitialized variable is an undefined behavior. You should prefer `time(NULL)`. Uninitialized variable method may introduce difficult to find bugs or may blow the computer.

Most of the time, effect observed would be, (on most implementation) above code would take (read) some leftover value from the stack that may be zero or something else but may be same on multiple runs defeating your purpose. `time` on the other hand is promising.

Comment: *" ... or may blow the computer"*   Seriously?

Comment: @RogerRowland One of my drama queen teacher once exaggerated UB that way. The point is, don't do it. Always write code with well defined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea. Undefined behaviour doesn't guarantee that you won't get the same seed on every run, which would be bad for randomness. It doesn't guarantee that your processor won't halt and catch fire either.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, so nothing guarantees anything.

Comment: Ok, I've made that more explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

Another point is that uninitialized variables can result in a [vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Uninitialized_Variable). So it is not only bad design and undefined behaviour, **it also can make your program exploitable**.

Consider [this code](http://rextester.com/TEXCI68859):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_uninitialized(void) {
    unsigned var;
    printf("%u\n", var);
}

void fake_init() {
    unsigned var=42;
}

int main(void) {
    print_uninitialized();
    fake_init();
    print_uninitialized();
}
```

Possible output:

```
0
42
```

[The next example](http://rextester.com/GCAVM19466) is a bit more realistic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned uninitialized( void ) {
    unsigned var;
    return var;
}

unsigned square(unsigned arg){
    unsigned result=arg*arg;
    return result;
}

int main( void ) {
    unsigned to_square;
    printf("UNINITIALIZED = %u\n", uninitialized());
    while(scanf("%u", &to_square)!=EOF){
        printf("%u * %u = %u\n", to_square, to_square, square(to_square));
        printf("UNITNITIALIZED = %u\n", uninitialized());
    }
}
```

The uninitialized variable can be modified by a user.

Input:

```
2
```

Output:

```
UNINITIALIZED = 0
2 * 2 = 4
UNITNITIALIZED = 4
```

Comment: [Another, IMO more realistic, example of exploitable code, relying on uninitialized variable](http://rextester.com/GCAVM19466). When compiled with no optimizations, user can control the value of uninitialized varaible.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case there are two possibilities:

- seed is a random variable (less possible)
- seed is constant on every run (more possible)

time(NULL) returns the time of the system which is 99.99% different every time you run the code.

Nothing is perfect random, but using time(NULL) gives you a "more random" number then if you would use the first approach.

You should check function's usage
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: Note in general the C++ community on SO prefers [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) over cplusplus.com