# Converting from integer to string in C

Tags: c

I want to convert an integer to a string in C.  I have tried the following code but the program is constantly outputting a 9-digit number. Does someone knows what is the error please and how can I fix it?

```
int num = 158;
char str[5];
sprintf(str, "%d" ,num);
printf("The result is: %d" , sprintf);
```

Thanks!

Comment: what about: `printf("The result is: %d", num);`

Comment: Well, you want to print `str` (not `sprintf`) with the `%s` (not `%d`) format. Doesn't your compiler warn you about the `sprintf`?

Comment: Also, 4 chars (plus null terminator) may be enough in your case, but it isn't for arbitrary `int`s. Might want to adjust the buffer size to 12 (to cater for -2147483648) and also use `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: you're printing the address of sprintf, typically a very large number, and you're also printing using the wrong format which results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 6):

Either you print the integer with %d

```
printf("The result is: %d\n", num);
```

or the string representation with %s

```
printf("The result is: %s\n" , str);
```

By doing

```
printf("The result is: %d" , sprintf);
```

You are printing the decimal representation of the address of the function sprintf. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int num = 158;
char str[5];
sprintf(str, "%d" ,num);
printf("The result is: %d\n", sprintf);
printf("The result is: %8x\n", sprintf);

}
```

Compile statically in order to make it easier to locate the address of sprintf.

```
➜  ~ [4] [Thu 13] $ gcc file.c -o bin -static
```

In the code, I also print the hexadecimal representation, which is easier to locate in the binary file. Output:

```
The result is: 4200768
The result is:   401940
```

You can actually check the linear address of sprintf in the ELF executable:

```
➜  ~ [4] [Thu 13] $ nm bin | grep sprintf
0000000000480830 W asprintf
0000000000480830 T __asprintf
0000000000480830 T ___asprintf
0000000000401940 T _IO_sprintf
0000000000480a40 T _IO_vasprintf
00000000004019d0 T __IO_vsprintf
00000000004019d0 T _IO_vsprintf
0000000000401940 T sprintf
0000000000401940 T __sprintf
0000000000480a40 W vasprintf
00000000004019d0 W vsprintf
```

As expected, 0x0000000000401940.

Comment: `As expected...` No it is UB, I did not expect anything. There should be no complaining even if the [computer blows up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882023/is-it-good-idea-to-pass-uninitialized-variable-to-srand/26882097#26882097).

Answer (score 3):

Change your printf to `printf("The result is: %s" , str);`.

`%s` is the specifier for strings and your string name is `str`. Printing with incorrect % specifiers invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("The result is: %d" , sprintf);
```

This code attempts to print `sprintf` which is a function. So its address is passed to `printf`. That's just not what you intended to do. Not to mention the fact that `%d` with an address leads to undefined behavior.

To print the string you made, you do this:

```
printf("The result is: %s", str);
```

Note that you must use the `%s` format string because the argument you supply is a string.

If all you want to do is to print the value, then you can remove `str`, remove the call to `sprintf`, and get `printf` to perform the formatting:

```
printf("The result is: %d", num);
```

One advantage of this is that it avoids you having to decide how large a buffer to allocate. You allocated a buffer with length 5 which can accept numbers up to 4 digits, or 3 digits if negative. For values with more digits, then your code will overrun that buffer.